# Confusion over the use of particle in this verb form 時を…鳴らせ…

Tags: grammar, syntax

This is a prologue to a Nintendo DS japan-exclusive videogame. It was never released overseas but received a fan-translation.

I'm very confused as to how the Japanese part is even grammatically correct. I thought the を + e verb form was only a command, or it meant the potential form.

> ２５年前のあの日から...
>
> この島の時間は...錆びついて止まったまま...
>
> **時を…鳴らせ…**
>
> ２５年の空白が動き出す…
>
> そして、刻みだした時の音が再びこの島に響き渡る…
>
> さぁ… あの惨劇をもう１度…
>
> ２５年前の惨劇をもう１度…

> 25 years ago on that day...
>
> This island... stopped in time...
>
> **Revive... time...**
>
> The frozen era comes to an end, resuming time.
>
> And then, the ticking of time once again echoes throughout...
>
> Now... Let's experience that tragedy once more...
>
> The tragedy 25 years ago that befalls again...

Answer (score 2):

> 時を…鳴らせ

Though you didn't clarify which line you were asking about, I'm assuming it's this one, as this is the only を + *verb* pattern I see in your text. (*Note*: the question has since been edited to provide highlighting on the appropriate sentence.)

時が鳴る　　→　Time resounds
時を鳴らす　→　(+ -らす ["causative" form](http://www.guidetojapanese.org/learn/grammar/causepass#Causative_Verbs)): [You/someone] let time resound
時を鳴らせ　→　(+ "imperative" form/"command"): Let time resound!

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I am grateful for any and all replies I get, be it praise or criticism. I hope all my posts are open to all and an opportunity to become a discussion.